# WGCNA consensus network using different soft threshold powers

Tags: r, list, networking

I am trying to create consensus network on 2 data sets using the WGCNA package on R. The sets have different connectivity at the same soft threshold power. I wonder how can I use a power of 11 on set1 and a power of 9 on set2 instead of 10 on both. Data is held on a list called multiExpr

Code is below:

```
softPower = 10;

adjacencies = array(0, dim = c(nSets, nGenes, nGenes));

for (set in 1:nSets)

adjacencies[set, , ] = abs(cor(multiExpr[[set]]$data, use = "p"))^softPower;
```

Comment: Have you tried scaling both your datasets? Check section 2.a.4 in this pdf:https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/Tutorials/Consensus-NetworkConstruction-man.pdf

Comment: I followed the steps presented in the tutorial and scaled the TOMs before creating the consensus one. My question is about Section 2.a.2 of that same tutorial.

Comment: what do the soft threshold plots look like?

Comment: I am trying to use one exponent in set1 and a different one in set2. I can create the adjacency matrices separately and then combine them in an array, but it may be an easier way to do that by slightly modifying the given code

Answer (score 1):

here is one answer:

```
softPower = c(9,11)
adjacencies = array(0, dim = c(nSets, nGenes, nGenes))

for (set in 1:nSets){
adjacencies[set, , ] = abs(cor(multiExpr[[set]]$data, use = "p"))^softPower[set]
}
```